# Unhandled exception at 0x77081d76 (ntdll.dll) in Stereo Vision.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll

I run (debug) my program about stereo vision and get this error. I also re-install Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, but this issue still appeared.

> Unhandled exception at 0x77081d76 (ntdll.dll) in Stereo Vision.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

I know something wrong with my dll or location of my project's result. But dunno how to solve it.

This is my code (too much .h and .cpp so I upload in dropbox):
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w7j0nrmcacr9frt/AAAVVrOmfCjQgS4dNh8hgF5Aa?dl=0

Could anyone help me?

Thanks.

p.s: I use VS 2010 Ultimate 32-bit and OpenCV 3.0

Comment: If you really "debugged" your program, you would, at the very least, took a look at the call stack to see where the problem originated.  And why would you believe reinstalling your compiler could solve the problem?  That doesn't accomplish anything, unless there was a problem with the actual compiler.

Comment: I got suggestion from friend that I might skip some installing process, and cause not sure I reinstall my VS. I check my call stack, in this is what I got >> ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart@8() + 0x1b bytes

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for answering me. I solved it. 
I just need to change **Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Run Time Library -> Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)**

Answer (score 0):

One solution I needed related to this issue was the ability to debug my C# code while this error prevented that from happening.

The solution was disabling native code debugging at the project level.